# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i / \sqrt{n} \Rightarrow W$ implies $EX_1^2 <\infty$ for an i.i.d. sequence $(X_i)$.

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables such that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i / \sqrt{n} $ converges in distribution to something. I want to show that $EX_1 ^2 <\infty$. (This is problem 3.4.3 of Durrett.)

The hint in the book suggests that if $EX_1 ^2 =\infty$, we define an independent copy of the sequence, say $X_i'$, and put $Y_i := X_i - X_i'$. Then put $U_i:=Y_i \mathbb 1_{|Y_i |\leq A}$ and $V_i:=Y_i \mathbb 1_{|Y_i |> A}$ for some $A>0$. Finally, for a fixed $K>0$,
$$P(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \geq K\sqrt n)\geq P(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \geq K\sqrt n , \sum_{i=1}^n V_i \geq 0 ) \geq 0.5 P(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \geq K\sqrt n ) \geq 0.2$$ and  he argues that this is a contradiction by taking $n$ to infinity.

I don't understand the second and third inequality above and the final limit part of his argument. Durrett suggests the inequality $P(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \geq K\sqrt n , \sum_{i=1}^n V_i \geq 0 ) \geq P(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \geq K\sqrt n , \sum_{i=1}^n V_i \leq 0 )$ follows from symmetry, but I don't see why (and this does imply the second inequality). Also, he uses the usual CLT in the third inequality, but we don't know whether $EU_1=0$. Likewise, we don't know if $EY_i=0$ hence the final limit process does not seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

---

For future visitors, the last argument is as follows;
by independence, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i /\sqrt{n}} (t)= \phi_{W} (t) \phi_{W} (-t) $ which has value $1$ and continuous at $t=0$, so we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i /\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to something. Finally take $K \to \infty$ to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> Proof.** By symmetry, $ Y'_i = U_i - V_i$ has the same distribution as $Y_i$. Moreover,

$$ Y'_i \mathbf{1}_{\{ |Y'_i| \leq A \}} = U_i \qquad\text{and}\qquad Y'_i \mathbf{1}_{\{ |Y'_i| > A \}} = -V_i. $$

So by replacing $Y_i$'s by $Y'_i$'s, we establish:

$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \geq 0 \right)
= \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \leq 0 \right). $$

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Proof.** Write $[n] = \{1, \dots, n\}$ for simplicity, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the random set of indices defined by

$$\mathcal{I} = \{ i \in [n] : |Y_i| \leq A\}.$$

Then we find that

- $\sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} Y_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i = \sum_{i \in [n]\setminus \mathcal{I}} Y_i$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal{I}$, and
- The conditional distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i$ given $\mathcal{I}$ is symmetric.

So by the law of iterated expectation,

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \geq 0 \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[
  \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \geq 0 \,\middle|\, \mathcal{I} \right)
  \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[
    \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \,\middle|\, \mathcal{I} \right) 
    \mathbb{P} \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \geq 0 \,\middle|\, \mathcal{I} \right)
  \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[
    \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \,\middle|\, \mathcal{I} \right) 
    \mathbb{P} \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \leq 0 \,\middle|\, \mathcal{I} \right)
  \right] \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i \geq K\sqrt{n} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i \leq 0 \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the fact that $Y_i'$ has the same distribution as $Y_i$ the core of your first proof? I think the second proof is more intuitive since it follows directly from the given conditions.

Comment: @izimath, I agree that the first proof might be trickier, and indeed, the "second" proof is actually the first argument that I came up with. However, I just could not help but include the first proof, since it is so short and elementary. It hinges on the fact that $$Y'_i\stackrel{d}=Y_i,\qquad U'_i=U_i,\qquad V'_i=-V_i,$$ where $U'_i$ and $V'_i$ are defined from $Y'_i$ in the same way $U_i$ and $V_i$ are defined from $Y_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any suggestions for the third inequality? I found that it suffices to show $EY_1 ^2 =\infty$ which is true if $X_1 \in L^1$. Is it possible to derive $X_1 \in L^1$ from the given assumptions?

Comment: @izimath, I do not believe that the third inequality is true for any $n$ and $A$. Rather, it is true only for large $n$ and $A$. Indeed, CLT shows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}U_i\geq K\sqrt{n}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left((\mathbb{E}[U^2])^{1/2}Z\geq K\right)$$ for a standard normal variable $Z$, and this limit converges to $\mathbb{P}(Z>0)=\frac{1}{2}$ as $A\to\infty$. So, for each given $K$, if $A$ is chosen large enough, then $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}U_i\geq K\sqrt{n}\right)\geq0.4$$ hold for all large $n$. Also, note that this is enough for our purpose.

Comment: Oh, I was asking why $\lim _{A\to \infty }\mathbb E[U^2] = \infty$ holds, which I believe boils down to showing $\mathbb E[Y_1^2] = \infty$. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @izimath, Sorry I misread your comment. For your question, let $\mu(\cdot)=\mathbb{P}(X\in\cdot)$ denote the law of $X$. Then by the change of variables formula and Fubini-Tonelli theorem, we have $$\mathbb{E}[(X-X')^2]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}[(X-x')^2]\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x')$$ where $X'$ is an i.i.d. copy of $X$. So if $\mathbb{E}[(X-X')^2]<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[(X-x')^2]<\infty$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x'$. This then implies that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]<\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112570/discussion-between-izimath-and-sangchul-lee).